# Find symfony 4 entity by user id?

Tags: php, symfony

So i have a ManyToOne relation between photo albums and a user.
When a user creates an album, his user_id is inserted into the album table.

How can i make a search query in my controller which will send the user_id field from my album table to my twig view ? The goal here is to only display the albums related to the current logged in user. (As you can see i am currently retrieving every album with the findAll() method).

AlbumController.php :

```
/**
 * @var AlbumRepository
 */
private $repository;
private $em;

/*Injection repository*/
public function __construct(AlbumRepository $repository, ObjectManager $em)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @Route("/admin", name="admin.album.index")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $albums = $this->repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('admin/album/index.html.twig', compact('albums'));
}
```

index.html.twig:

```
{% for album in albums %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ album.title }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('admin.album.edit', {id: album.id}) }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Editer</a>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ path('admin.album.delete', {id: album.id}) }}"style="display: inline-block"
                          onsubmit="return confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cet album ?')">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token(('delete' ~ album.id)) }}">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

[My album table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yahP.png)

[My user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXx9.png)

I really hope that i was clear in describing my issue, note that i am a beginner developper so i might have missed something.

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `Album` entity has a user property.

You can fetch albums by user like this :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$albums = $this->repository->findBy([
  'user' => $user // you can pass the user id or a user object
]);
```